# Adding Custom Thread

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi I have developed the inventor API program it work fine both in Local and also the Cloud. i have one Clarification regarding the design data. We are using some additional custom hole feature with respect to customer requirement. How to modify the Design Data file i.e Thread.xls file before executing the Inventor API

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using excel file, if it just data, you better use csv file, which is easy to modify the data without using any external library.

Answer (score 0):

There are several XLSX libraries available, such as https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelLibrary/